# Proof of the existence of the infimum of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ then $f$ has a minimum on $\mathbb{R}$, that is there is an $x_m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x_m) = \operatorname{inf}\left\{f(x): x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

Attempt:
$f$ is defined on the whole real line and continuous.  Restrict ourselves to some smaller domain $[a,b] \neq (-\infty, \infty)$ assuming WLOG $a < b$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\exists x_o \in (a,b) $ such that $f(x_o) = y_o$. Since $f(x) \rightarrow \infty $ as $ x \rightarrow -\infty$, in this interval take $f(x_o) = \operatorname{inf}\left\{f(x)\right\}$

Is it okay?

Comment: You want to use the fact that a continuous function on a compact interval attains its infimum (and supremum). This has nothing to do with the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty,$$ then for each real $\alpha$ there exists $M>0$ such that $f(x)>\alpha$ whenever $|x|>M$.

Take any $x_0\in\Bbb R$. If $f(x_0)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, then we're done. If not, then find $M>0$ such that $f(x)>f(x_0)$ whenever $|x|>M$. We can minimize $f$ on $[-M,M]$. (Which not-yet-used hypothesis allows this?) What can we then conclude?

---

Your approach is rather odd. What is $y_0$, and how does it help us? It seems you have (most of) the appropriate pieces, but you went a peculiar direction with them.

---

**Edit**: You've got all the pieces now. Let me help you put the rest of it together. Since $f$ is continuous on $[-M,M]$, then by Extreme Value Theorem, there is some $x_1\in[-M,M]$ such that $f(x_1)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in[-M,M]$. Since $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for all $|x|>M$, then in particular, we can't have $|x_0|>M$, so $x_0\in[-M,M].$ By our choice of $x_1$, then $f(x_1)\leq f(x_0)$, so $f(x_1)\leq f(x)$ for $|x|>M$. Since we also have $f(x_1)\leq f(x)$ for $x\in[-M,M]$--that is, for $|x|\le M$--then $f(x_1)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, as desired.

Comment: The not-yet used hypothesis would be the Extreme Value Theorem. The interval $[-M,M]$ satisfies the EVT and so there exists say $x_o \in [-M,M]$ such that $f(x_o) = \operatorname{inf}_{x \in [-M,M]}$.  Is it good?

Comment: Close! The not-yet-used hypothesis is the continuity of $f$. It will allow us to use the EVT, though. Since we've already used $x_0$, we should pick $x_1\in[-M,M]$ such that $f(x_1)=\inf\{f(x):x\in[-M,M]\}$. We then need only show that $f(x_1)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R.$ It will help to note that $x_0\in[-M,M]$, and recall how $M$ was chosen.

Comment: In $[-N,N]$, $f(x) \leq f(x_o)\,\forall x$.  Since by the EVT, the minimum exists, so let $x =x_1$, where $x_1$ gives $f(x_1)$ as defined above.

Comment: We can't say that $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ for all $x$ in $[-M,M]$. We can only say that $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for all $x$ that **aren't** in $[-M,M]$. For an example where we can't draw the conclusion you're hoping to draw, let $f(x)=(x-1)^2(x+1)^2$, $x_0=\frac12,$ $M=1$. Then $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for all $x$ that aren't in $[-M,M]$, but for example $f(0)>f(x_0)$ and $0\in[-M,M]$. I've updated my answer to put the rest of the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate value theorem does not apply. If you restrict the function to any closed interval [a,b] there will be a minimum in that range because f restricted to a closed interval has a maximum and a minimum. However, f may dip to to a lower value outside of this range before it grows to infinity. Therefore, the minimum of f in [a,b] is not necessarily the minimum of the function over the whole real line.

You must choose your interval so that the minimum on that interval is the minimum over the whole line. Since f goes to infinity as x gets small, we know that we can choose a so that x < a implies f(x) > 1. This set is bounded below and so has a greatest lower bound. f is continuous so we can find c so that f(c) equals that greatest lower bound. Likewise, there exists b so that x > b > a implies f(x) > 1 and that set has a lower bound so we can find d so that f(d) equals that greatest lower bound. Now the minimum of f on [c,d] should do the trick.